# Display image on top of another image on rollover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mousehover

I want to display a zoom image (on mouseover) on top of certain images to imply 'click here to zoom'. I don't want to use a cursor.

I'm sure there's a good way to do this with javascript jQuery but I don't know it.

Does anyone have any good ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTML:

```
<a href='big.jpg'>
    <img src='mini.jpg' alt='a kitten'>
    <span>Click to view larger</span>
</a>
```

CSS:

```
a > img + span {display: none}
a:hover > img + span {display: inline}
```

Then style however you like.

Comment: One minor caveat: IE5 is unsupported.

Answer (score 1):

[This jQuery plugin](http://cssglobe.com/lab/tooltip/02/) seems to do what you want, and you can easily customise it to fit your needs (i.e. implement click).

Comment: A fellow Kiwi from the Tron. Greetings :)

Comment: That would work, except I need the ability to have the user click to open a larger version of the image. This script is using an <a> tag to display the small mag. glass image. Am I missing something?

Comment: Yep so do a view source and you'll see he's using the $("a.preview").hover(function(e){}. You can easily change that to use click(), but you'll need a separate function for closing the image (i.e. clicking the large version) since that's currently using the "mouseout" event.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to use a zoom icon instead of the pointer cursor? Mozilla supports a zoom-cursor (http://www.worldtimzone.com/mozilla/testcase/css3cursors.html) but you will have to face the problem on IE. Perhaps you can have a hidden div with your custom zoom-icon like: `<div style="display:none" id="zoomcursor">yourcursor</div>` then you can play with the images and jquery:

```
$('img.zoomthis').mouseover(function(){
    var pos = $(this).position();
    $('#zoomcursor').css("position","absolute");
    $('#zoomcursor').css("top",pos.top+18);//You have to change this in order to place it right over your image
    $('#zoomcursor').css("left",$(obj).width()-30); //this too
    $('#zoomcursor').show();
}).mouseout(function(){
    $('#zoomcursor').hide();
})
```